# MediaWiki default category

Tags: mediawiki

I've recently set up the newest MediaWiki install. I'm trying to force users to make an article part of a certain category. I'm using the SelectCategory extension to ask them when editing an article, however it is possible that they don't select any categories and simply save the page without it being attached to a category.

Is there a way (extension/setting/hack) that I can make a default category that all new articles will be a part of if they aren't added in another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that I know of which leaves you with only a few options:

1. Modify the SelectCategory to force selection of a category.
2. Modify MediaWiki code, or create a new extension, to force a category selection.
3. Perform the category selection post-editing (patrols, bots, manual editing, etc...).

Keep in mind that if you edit any MediaWiki code it will be difficult to upgrade in the future. Ideally you probably want to create a custom extension that does what you want. I haven't done any category related MediaWiki coding but the latest versions generally have enough hooks that you can do most things via an extension relatively easily.

Comment: I was thinking modifying SelectCategory would be the easier option for a non-php programmer. I'm just trying to comb through the source and find where it generates the checkboxes and auto-check the Uncategorized one. No luck yet.